# A concrete example using the html5 stream-api

Tags: api, html, streaming

I'd like to know if someone succeeded in using the [HTML5 stream api](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#stream-api)?
How can I use it? Is is it a "serverless" solution? If not, where the stream is sent?

(I found this [blog entry](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-implementing-device-and-stream-management-webkit) that shows the first html5 conference app with a customized webkit. It's really interesting but not useful since it's not a standerized).

Thank you,

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream API is part of the `HTMLDeviceElement` API. This has not been implemented in any released browser as of yet (Jan 2011).

The stream is served by the client computer. It is theoretically a "serverless" solution since it's meant as a client-side API to expose the client's devices (webcams, USB devices, etc). You could use JavaScript to send the stream to a server if desired.

Since there are no released implementations (aside from the WebKit nightlies it seems), this spec is not really ready to be used.

You could always try a [WebKit nightly build](http://nightly.webkit.org/) and see if the demo you linked to works for you. Since this is not released yet, I wouldn't expect anything to work very well. I tried running the latest nightly (WebKit-r74232) and it seems `HTMLDeviceElement` is not enabled at the moment.

Comment: That what I thought. Don't you think there is peer-to-peer javascript stream solution?

Comment: @Zakaria It looks like part of the spec outlines Peer to Peer connections, but it's currently still in the "idea" phase and doesn't have many details yet. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/commands.html#peer-to-peer-connections

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if a "temporary" javascript library exists allowing the peer-to-peer streaming? Thanks.

Comment: @Zakaria Not that I'm aware of. If it were possible, it would require each node to have a web server configured on their machines, with some sort of executable code running (not JavaScript) to make it possible to interpret messages.